# Query in autosuggest script in multiple fields based on first field input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, autosuggest

I am currently modifying an out-of-the-box php/jQuery autosuggestion script. I have the following issues:

I have two form fields with autosuggest. The first field is for the user to input a city. So my php file `autosuggest.php` queries DB and finds matches that have `parent = 9` (this is all the cities). Now for the second field, where the user inputs `school`, i want my php to query through DB and find the schools that have the entered city as parent.

I am trying to solve this by storing the String returned from PHP to the javascript (when the user has entered a city) to a `SESSION` variable. And then use this session variable as parent when the `autosuggest.php` queries to find matches for the SECOND form.

But I can't get this to work. I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in

autosuggest.php on line 47 (LIKE '$queryString%').
```

But it goes away if I comment out or remove the `$parent = $termquery;` line in `autosuggest.php`.

Here is my code:

**index.php contains this sript:**

```
<?php session_start();?>
<script>

    var globEl = "";
    function suggest(inputString){
        var activeEle = document.activeElement.id;
        globEl = activeEle;
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        } else if(activeEle == "city") {
            $('#city').addClass('load');
            $.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                    $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#city').removeClass('load');
                }
            });
        } else if(activeEle == "school") {
            $('#school').addClass('load');
            $.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                    $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#school').removeClass('load');
                }
            });
        }   
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        if (globEl == 'city') {
            $('#city').val(thisValue);
            $.post('update_session.php', {parentnamee: thisValue});
            setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 0);
        } else if(globEl == 'school') {
            $('#school').val(thisValue);
            $.post('update_session.php', {parentnamee: thisValue});
            setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 0);
        } 
    }


</script>
```

**update_session.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['foreldrenavnn'] = $_POST['foreldrenavnn'];
?>
```

**autosuggest.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $db_host = 'host';
    $db_username = 'user';
    $db_password = 'passw';
    $db_name = 'db';
    $parent = 9;

    $db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username ,$db_password, $db_name);

if(!$db) {

    echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
} else {

    if(isset($_SESSION['parentnamee'])) {
        $parentstring = $db->real_escape_string($_SESSION['parentnamee']);

        if(strlen($parentstring) >0) {
            $termquery = $db->query("
            SELECT wp_terms.term_id
            FROM wp_terms
            WHERE wp_terms.name='$parentstring%'
            ");
            $parent = $termquery;
        }

    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("
            SELECT wp_terms.name
            FROM wp_terms
            INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
            ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
            AND wp_term_taxonomy.parent=$parent
            WHERE wp_terms.name
            LIKE '$queryString%'
            LIMIT 10
            ");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                if($query) {
                echo '<ul>';
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->name).'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';       
                    }   
                echo '</ul>';

                } else {
                    echo 'OOPS we had a problem :(';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<span style="color:#0196E3";>'.$queryString.'</span> no matches.';
                echo '</ul>';
            }   
        } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        } else {
            echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Anyone have any ideas what i am doing wrong? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: based strictly on the php error, i'd say `$db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);` isn't returning a string.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct. But why? The problem disappears when I comment out the '$parent = $termquery;', so I am guessing that after getting the $parent variable from session, it is not a string. But why is that? Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: I'm just diagnosing what i see. Commenting out that line should have no effect on the error, unless it itself is causing a separate error, or preventing you from even reaching that line.

Comment: Maybe it's time to add some debugging messages into the script to see what the value of certain variables are throughout the code?

Comment: @KevinB Yes, good suggestion! Can you point me in a direction? I am very new to php and jQuery. How do I do this?